# Is it possible for a object property in JavaScript to be non-printable but iterable?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, properties, hidden

I have an object which when printed (**JSON.stringify(...)**) does not show a property that is shown when I iterate through the object using a for loop

`(for(var prop in object){...})`.

Is this possible or has anyone encountered this mysterious behavior before?

Comment: Could you show us the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when the value associated with the property is not a *valid JSON data type*.
Valid data types are numbers, booleans, strings, arrays and objects.

Every other type of variable is non-primitive. For example, a callback, an instance of a class or a DOM element.

So, if you do `json.stringify({"prop1" : 5, "prop2" : function(){}})`, you will get `prop1` but not `prop2` (whereas both will appear when you iterate with `for`loop).